# Internationalisation with ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid

From this page: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-internationalisation/ I can't find how to change the `AND` and `OR` words of the filter:
[image]

Comment: for what\or by what you wanna change it?

Comment: @un.spike sorry I didn't understand your question.

Comment: So, basically you can't change inbuilt features, but you can create own `filterComponenet` with own logic and needed things.

Comment: yes u're right but I wanted to use the basic filter so I don't want a custom filter

Comment: just wondering how they made every word changeable except those two XD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for version 17.1.1

> ag-grid\src\ts\filter\baseFilter.ts

There no translation for those parts

```
const DEFAULT_TRANSLATIONS: {[name: string]: string}= {
    loadingOoo:'Loading...',
    equals:'Equals',
    notEqual:'Not equal',
    lessThan:'Less than',
    greaterThan:'Greater than',
    inRange:'In range',
    lessThanOrEqual:'Less than or equals',
    greaterThanOrEqual:'Greater than or equals',
    filterOoo:'Filter...',
    contains:'Contains',
    notContains:'Not contains',
    startsWith: 'Starts with',
    endsWith: 'Ends with',
    searchOoo: 'Search...',
    selectAll: 'Select All',
    applyFilter: 'Apply Filter',
    clearFilter: 'Clear Filter'
};
```

for the latest version it's still not in `translations`, code part is [here](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/f065d96ee682d4c43a7275f35935d122d9faeee6/packages/ag-grid-community/src/ts/filter/baseFilter.ts#L236)

```
this.addDestroyableEventListener(andButton, 'change', () => {
            this.conditionValue = 'AND';
            this.onFilterChanged();
        });
        this.addDestroyableEventListener(orButton, 'change', () => {
            this.conditionValue = 'OR';
            this.onFilterChanged();
        });
```

So they've just hardcode it, need to create an issue in their zendesk.

> Update [version 20.2](https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-changelog/?fixVersion=20.2.0) added support for filter 'AND/OR' localization

```
// filter conditions
andCondition: 'AND',
orCondition: 'OR',
```

Comment: hmm that's sad :(

Comment: I have already opened and issue and they answered me https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/2660 . They will fix it in the future version, I hope :). Thanks for your time my friend

Comment: @SlimenTN JFI on 20.2.0v they've fixed  (and added)  'AND\OR' translations `AG-2716`

Answer (score 0):

TS:

```
public localeText: {
    [key: string]: string;
} = AG_GRID_LOCALE_FR;

gridOptions: GridOptions = {
    localeText: this.localeText,
};
```

HTML:

```
<ag-grid-angular
#agGrid
class="ag-theme-alpine"
...
[gridOptions]="gridOptions"
```

> 

create translation file:

```
export const AG_GRID_LOCALE_FR { ... }
```

Comment: default translation file here: https://www.ag-grid.com/examples/localisation/localisation/locale.en.js